# log4net issue when F# script calls C# exe

Tags: c#, f#, log4net

I got an C# exe which writes log4net logs. If I run this exe directly, the logging works ok.
However, if I call the exe from a F# script (with extension fsx), I have the error

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application'
s .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> e
lements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" typ
e="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

anyone can help? thanks a lot

Comment: Can you include the F# code that is calling the C# exe in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert configuration of this exe file to configuration file of your f# application or initialize logger in code. I am not sure that when you run f# script there are config file.

You can try to set config to configfile of your c# exe with code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "c:/test.config);
```

Comment: F# scripts are run by F# Interactive (fsi.exe).

Comment: thanks, i know. You can try to set config to config file of your c# app with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "c:/test.config");

Comment: I just meant that the relevant config file for an F# script will be fsi.exe.config.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work... Try to setup in code config as i wrote.

Comment: found out that you just cannot rely on default or current directory when invoking a piece of code from another piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

When you call your C# .exe from F# Interactive, the current working directory -- which is where .NET will try to load the .config file from -- is the directory where F# Interactive is installed.

In your F# interactive script, do something like this:

```
// Change the current directory to the directory where the
// C# assembly was loaded from.
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <-
    // TODO : Change 'MyType' to any public type from your C# assembly
    typeof<FSharpx.Text.Lexing.Position>.Assembly.Location
```

**EDIT :** On second thought, I don't know if the above code will work -- it assumes the .config file will be lazily loaded (i.e., on-demand). If the CLR loads the .config file at the same time the .exe is loaded, you'll need to do something like this instead:

```
// Change the current directory *before* referencing the C# assembly.
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory <- @"C:\blah";;

// Reference the C# assembly
#r @"C:\blah\foobar.exe";;
```